# Echoing data depending on input

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a sign-up form that has two entries.

I have a `index.php` file that displays the form and an external PHP file that adds the details. I have an `if` statement on the external PHP file that will say if the user details were successful or not.

I want to have either the successful or failed comment to show in a div under the form without refreshing the page.
I'm sorry to ask but I have looked all over the place and I just don't seem to understand how to do it.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["username"] );
$password = mysql_real_escape_string( md5($_POST["password"]) );

if( empty($username) || empty($password) ) {
    echo "Username and Password Required";
    exit();
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$username', '$password')" ;

if( mysql_query($sql) ) {
    echo "Inserted Successfully";
}
if(! mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo "Insertion Failed";
}

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $("#submit").click( function() {   
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $('#register');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'reg.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: form.serialize(),
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                alert(data);
                form.reset();
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form id="reg" action="login.php" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Register Form</legend>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter      Username"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign-Up" onclick="load()"/>

            </fieldset> 
        </form>
        <div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is the with the use of deprecated mysql_* functionality, it is better to use mysqli or PDO for this.

For my example I will use mysqli. The first place you have gone wrong is by using `md5`, it is weak and not very secure, so I will use `password_hash` for this, also the way you use *"sanitize"* your parameters (`$username` & `$password`) could be a lot better, using built in functions from mysqli can help a lot with this.

Please see my code below:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username']; //Set the username
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT); //Hash the password properly, md5 is weak!

//Set up the link
$link = mysqli_init();
$link->real_connect("hostname", "ServerUsername", "ServerPassword", "dbname");

//Prepare the query (using named params for this, i.e. :username and :password
$query = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (:username, :password);");
//Bind the username
$query->bind_param(":username", $username);
//Bind the password
$query->bind_param(":password", $password);
//Execute the query
$query->execute();
//Set the result to a variable
$query->bind_result($result);

//Check inserted or not
if ($result)
    echo "Inserted";
else
    echo "Failed to insert";

?>
```

Using `prepare`, `bind_param` and `bind_result` will benefit you as you only want a bare result for a true||false comparison.

If you need further explanation, please let me know :)

A better way to do your AJAX call would be to have it all within the single `$.ajax({...})` call, e.g.:

```
$( document ).ready( function ()
{
    $( "#submit" ).on( "click", function ()
    {
        $.ajax( {
            url: "reg.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function ( response )
            {
                $( "#area_id" ).html( response );
            },
            beforeSend: function ()
            {
                $( "#area_id" ).html( "Loading..." );
            },
            error: function()
            {
                $( "#area_id" ).html( "Failed to load." );
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

A good thing to do would be to use a ternary operator for the `true||false` check you have, namely:

```
mysql_query($query);
echo ((mysql_affected_rows($connection) > 0) ? "Inserted" : "Failed");
//Where $connection is the connection to the DB
```

Ternary operators are like saying

```
if (mysql_affected_rows($connection) > 0) 
{
    echo "inserted"; 
} 
else
{
    echo "Failed";
}
```

They are sometimes referred to as a *shorthand if else statement*

Comment: wow that scared me haha. I'm useless at programming. I'm just looking to do the basic stuff correct. What i have done is working and linked to a database but its just when i want it to say something like "you need a username" or successful.

Comment: @john, I have added an edit to the bottom, maybe it is what you are looking for?

Comment: @john, has this helped at all? Besides, I don't think there is such as things as a useless programmer, but someone who is learning or may be better at certain things than other things, me for example, I'm better at the backend frameworks than the front :P

Comment: i understand what your saying but im still having the problem that when the button is clicked it opens a new window and says successful or you need a username and password.

Comment: What is the element that you use for the `$("#submit")`? Can you add it to your question or add it as a comment on here? It could be that which is causing the new page to be shown

Comment: Or return false directly after the ajax call

Comment: Nearly all my code it there now. Im just doing the basic and learn from that

Comment: the script and body are in the same php file while the other code with the if statements are in an external php file

Comment: One thing to be said, there is nothing with the `id` of `submit`, you have a named element for this, but for `$("#submit")` to work, it needs to be an ID. I am looking into the other part now for you.

Comment: sorry i was changing it around. The button has an id of submit so when that was clicked i wanted it to go to the script

Comment: I'm looking into this not for you :P

Comment: New answer added for you, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this, and found many problems.

What you can do is copy and paste this code and see what's different from the original.

**reg.php**

```
<?php
//Check if the request variables are set
$username = isset($_REQUEST['username']) ? $_REQUEST['username'] : "Not Set";
$password = isset($_REQUEST['password']) ? $_REQUEST['password'] : "Not Set";
print "{$username}<br />{$password}";
//Do whatever you need to
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready( function ()
        {
            $( "#submit" ).on( "click", function ()
            {
                console.log("reg.php?username=" + $( "#username" ).val() + "&password=" + $( "#password" ).val());
                $.ajax( {
                    url: "reg.php?username=" + $( "#username" ).val() + "&password=" + $( "#password" ).val(),
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function ( response )
                    {
                        $( "#res" ).html( response );
                    },
                    beforeSend: function ()
                    {
                        $( "#res" ).html( "Loading..." );
                    }
                } );
            } );
        } );
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Register form</legend>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <button id="submit">Sign up</button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="res"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What you had was an action that took you to `login.php`, this was why you got the redirect to the other page. I removed the form and the submit in place of a button, this allows for more control and means you can use JavaScript to change the location.

Also, parts of your JavaScript were false, can't remember which now! So these have been removed and optimised.

Comment: I have it that when i button it clicked it says loading but nothing else. Is that correct. I have 3 php files in total two of which you have seen and the 3rd is just the connection to the database.

Comment: Are you printing anything in the `reg.php` file? If you don't then the `Loading...` will always show as it thinks there hasn't been a success to print into the area, even if you do not print the result in the div, but use it for some other logic, you need to give the client something back

Comment: Also, when you use an external file with the database connections, a file that has been AJAXed to does not know this exists, either you need to recreate the connection in that file, or include the file in the `reg.php` file

Comment: it shows up the username and password under the form but i checked the phpMyAdmin database and it didnt update it like before

Comment: That may be because in my code I have not done anything for an insert or update, you'd need to add this to your code

Comment: Also, have you checked that the connection is available in the reg.php file as I said before?

Comment: ive added the db.php file into the login.php file you sent me and it didnt work. Maybe ill just give up im too long at this.

Comment: One last thing to try, put the PHP source straight into the code (for the db work I mean) and if that doesn't work, there is a problem with the SQL

Comment: its fine thanks for your help. Ill just put it back the way it was. i dont really know how to fix it but i can prevent a new window from opening when the button is clicked but i cant say successful or not. I know its hard for you to try make me understand without seeing all the code and files together.